# Tikz Picture in chapter title and spacing to to chapter body

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning

The following minimal working example

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}                                                     
\usepackage{tikz}                                                      
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}                                        
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}                                            
%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}                           
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]  % type (section,chapter,etc...) to vary,  shape (eg display-type)
        {\normalfont\bfseries\Huge} % format of the chapter            
        {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}     % the label            
        {0pt} % separation between label and chapter-title             
          {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]               
    \node[yshift=-8cm] at (current page.north west)                    
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]                  
        \draw[fill=black] (0,0) rectangle(35.5mm,15mm);                
        \node[anchor=north east,yshift=-7.2cm,xshift=34mm,minimum
height=30mm,inner sep=0mm] at (current page.north west)
        {\parbox[top][30mm][t]{15mm}{\raggedleft
$\phantom{\textrm{l}}$\color{white}\chapterlabel}};  %the black l is just to get better base-line alingement
        \node[anchor=north west,yshift=-7.2cm,xshift=37mm,text
width=\textwidth,minimum height=30mm,inner sep=0mm] at (current
page.north west)
              {\parbox[top][30mm][t]{\textwidth}{\color{black}#1}};    
       \end{tikzpicture}                                               
      };                                                               
   \end{tikzpicture}                                                   
   \gdef\chapterlabel{}                                                
  } % code before the title body 
\begin{document}
\frontmatter                                                           
{\huge TITLE} \\[24pt]
\setcounter{page}{0}
\mainmatter
\chapter{A very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very long title}
\lipsum[7]

\end{document}
```

Produces the following chapter page:
[image]

The problem is that the spacing between text body and chapter title is not correct. The spacing seems to be calculated with respect to the bottom of the black rectangle, but not with respect to the bottom of the chapter title.

Is it possible to adjust the spacing such that the distance between text body and chapter title is always the same (independent of the number of lines needed by the chapter title)?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the `overlay` option the height of the chapter title is not taken into account. But there is no need to use `tikz`.

Here is a suggestion using a black `\colorbox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
        {\normalfont\bfseries\Huge}
        {\makebox[.5ex][r]{\colorbox{black}{%
            \hspace*{5cm}\rule[-1.5mm]{0pt}{13mm}\color{white}\thechapter\,%
          }}\,}
        {0pt}{#1}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
{\huge TITLE\par}
\mainmatter
\chapter[short title]{A very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very long title}
\lipsum[7]
\setcounter{chapter}{99}
\chapter[short title]{A very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very long title}
\lipsum[7]
\end{document}
```

[image]